# Wildfly Error While Deploying Spring boot app with mssql server dependncy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, wildfly, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to deploy my spring boot project war on wildfly but getting below error. I am pasting the whole error log for the reference.

```
 WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
("subsystem" => "datasources"),
("data-source" => "MySqlDSIM")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable depen
dencies" => [
"org.wildfly.data-source.MySqlDSIM is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.IssueManage
mentWeb_war_com_mysql_cj_jdbc_Driver_8_0]",
"jboss.driver-demander.java:/MySqlDSIM is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.IssueMa
nagementWeb_war_com_mysql_cj_jdbc_Driver_8_0]"
]}
13:57:26,721 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Bo
ot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
("subsystem" => "datasources"),
("data-source" => "MySqlDSIM")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable depen
dencies" => [
"org.wildfly.data-source.MySqlDSIM is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.IssueManage
 mentWeb_war_com_mysql_cj_jdbc_Driver_8_0]",
"jboss.driver-demander.java:/MySqlDSIM is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.IssueMa
nagementWeb_war_com_mysql_cj_jdbc_Driver_8_0]",
"org.wildfly.data-source.MySqlDSIM is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.IssueManage
 mentWeb_war_com_mysql_cj_jdbc_Driver_8_0]"
 ]}
```

Comment: It says it is missing dependencies. You need to add those dependencies.

Comment: To expand on what @Christine said, you're missing the MySQL JDBC driver